# Controls FX TraversalEngine Error

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I installed `JDK8u20` and tried to run my program with the `ControlsFX` library in it.

This should work fine, but if I call a method from controlsFX, I get the following exception

**Method**

```
 private void showError(final String msg) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Dialogs.create().title("Achtung").message(msg).showError();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal.TraversalEngine.<init>(Ljavafx/scene/Parent;Z)V
    at org.controlsfx.control.ButtonBar$2.<init>(ButtonBar.java:412)
    at org.controlsfx.control.ButtonBar.<init>(ButtonBar.java:412)
    at org.controlsfx.control.ButtonBar.<init>(ButtonBar.java:355)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.createButtonPanel(Dialog.java:1034)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.createCenterPanel(Dialog.java:1029)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.buildDialogContent(Dialog.java:950)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:320)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs.showSimpleContentDialog(Dialogs.java:1106)
    at org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs.showError(Dialogs.java:555)
    at ch.berufsbildungscenter.notiztool.gui.control.LoginController$3.run(LoginController.java:93)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1171794308.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1875594551.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/994750745.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What version of ControlsFX are you using? If you go to the [main page](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) you will see that there is a specific version for 8u20.

Comment: controlsfx-8.0.6 @assylias

Comment: You need controlsfx-8.0.6_20

Comment: You will find [controlsfx-8.0.6_20 here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.controlsfx|controlsfx|8.0.6_20|)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha thanks for your help :) didn't know that 8.0.6 is not compatible with jre 8_20.

Comment: @assylias thanks too :) close this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Adding an answer for someone facing the same issue in future :*

`ControlsFX 8.0.6` was released in two separate releases

- ControlsFX 8.0.6, for developers using JavaFX 8.0
- ControlsFX 8.0.6_20, for developers building with JavaFX 8u20

If you are wondering why ? [here is an explanation to it](http://fxexperience.com/2014/05/announcing-controlsfx-8-0-6/)

If you are using JDK8, go with [ControlsFX 8.0.6](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-8.0.6.zip)

If you are using JDK8_20 or later, go with [ControlsFX 8.0.6_20](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-8.0.6_20.zip)